# Custom File for Launch Screen

Tags: ios, swift, xib

I'm making an app where I need to program the launch screen, more than just placing images on the .xib file. Is there a way to connect a swift file to the launch screen so I can add animations?

I was thinking of doing something like Supercell does for Clash of Clans, where there's a loading bar and a short message users can look at while the game loads.

So is it possible to connect a swift class file to the .xib launch screen and how would one go about doing it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately your app cannot process or display any animations during this launch screen. This is because the app is still technically loading.

Also it contradicts Apple's design guidelines for launch screens:

> Design a plain launch image that improves the user experience. In
>   particular, the launch image isn’t an opportunity to provide:
>
> An “app entry experience,” such as a splash screen
>
> An About window
>
> Branding elements, unless they are a static part of your app’s first
>   screen

What you can do is add your own custom "animation screen" as the entry point to your Storyboard (or just root view) and create animations as you normally would through a View Controller swift file.